# How to display powerpivot chart on sharepoint web page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a chart in excel using powerpivot because power view and dashboard designer do not appear to have the capabilities I need for charting, specifically the ability to display as percentage.

I would like to display the chart on a sharepoint page much the same way the dashboard designer publishes a chart to a page. I have used a page viewer web part to display the spreadsheet but it is not as clean because it loads excel.

are there more seamless ways to embed either the spreadsheet or its chart on a page so that it looks like the dashboard charts?sharepoint dashboard deployment does use web parts which is fine - but it doesn't show excel or other junk from content creators.

sharepoint 2013 sp1, farm sql server 2012 sp2, windows server 2012 r2, ssas with tabular mode

Answer (score 2):

seek and ye shall find.....I found the perfect solution to my problem by using the excel web part. it is documented here with a very good video demonstration: http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint2013ExcelGraph.htm